# Does length of indexed field matter while searching?

Tags: mongodb, chat, mongoose-schema

The chat app schema that I have is something like below.

```
1. conversations {participants[user_1, user_2], convsersation_id}
2. messages {sender: user_1, sonversation_id, timestamps}
```

I want to  map this relationship using existing `_id:ObjectId` which is already indexed.

But  if I want to get all conversation of `user_1` I have to first search in which conversation that user is involed and get that conversation's `_id` and again search for the messages in `messages` using that conversation `_id`. 
So my questions are - 

Does length of indexed field (here `_id`) matters while searching?
Should I create another shorter indexed fields?.
Also if there is any better alternative schema please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to maintain the data as sub documents instead of array. The advantage you have is you can build another index (only) on `conversation_id` field, which you want to query to know the user's involvement

When you maintain it as array, you cannot index the `converstaion_id` field separately, instead you will have to build a multi key index, which indexes all the elements of the array (`sender` and `timestamps` fields) which you are never going to use for querying and it also increases the index size

Answering you questions:
Does length of indexed field (here _id) matters while searching? - *Not really*
Should I create another shorter indexed fields? - *Create sub-document and index* `converstaion_id`
Also if there is any better alternative schema please suggest. - *Maintain the array fields as sub-documents*

Comment: Actually it was my mistake but you should know that these two `conversation` and `messages` are collections. Now you can suggest thanks.